# Typo3 Custom filed on Content Element

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Can I add a custom field to each content-element where I can add a string?

In typoscript I would be able to read this string and print it in `class=""` attribute is that possible?

There is the note field for each content element Can I red this in typoscript and paste it in the class attribute?

```
CONTENT < styles.content.get
CONTENT.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap=<div class="{NOTE??}">|</div>
```

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Is something like this possible:

```
CONTENT < styles.content.get
CONTENT.renderObj.stdWrap {

    key.field = layout

    4 = TEXT        

    4.value = <div class="csc-default blue">|</div>



    5 = TEXT
    5.value = <div class="csc-default meineklasse2">|</div>



    6 = TEXT
    6.value = <div class="csc-default meineklasse3">|</div>



}
```

Comment: I think you want to layout the content element? Maybe you can use the layout field for your own needs?

Comment: Can you give me an example how I can use the layout field to add custom css as wrapper of the content element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to stay with a given CI it normally is no good option to enable editors to enter CSS-class names by hand. A better way would be to have a set of possible classes the editor can choose from.

This can be done if you use the already available field `layout` in the `tt_content`record.

As the `layout`field is type `int` you might need a 'translation' to your expected class names, or you stay with numbered classes like `frame-layout-1` to `frame-layout-3`. This is the (in FSC) build in solution and available option.

You can enhance this option and also modify it.
Enhancing the selection is done in  page TSconfig:

```
// Adding more layouts:
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.addItems {
    4 = my special layout
    5 = my other special layout
}

// Modifying layouts names:
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.altLabels {
    1 = my default layout
}

// remove items
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.removeItems = 2,3
```

In FSC this field is evaluated in the layout template (`Resources/Private/Layouts/Default.html`) (if you also use a `frame_class` ????)

```
[...]
<div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame frame-{data.frame_class} frame-type-{data.CType} frame-layout-{data.layout}{f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: ' frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: ' frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')}">
[...]
```

But you can override the `Default.html` file with your own, like in every fluid templating system. Just copy the original file to your own space and add the new location to the template (Layout) paths.
That could end in something like:

```
[...]
<div id="c{data.uid}" {f:render.section(name:'layout-selection', arguments={layout:'layout'})} ... >
[...]

<f:section name="layout-selection">
    <f:switch expression="{layout}">
        <f:case value="1">class="normal"</f:case>
        <f:case value="4">class="special"</f:case>
        <f:case value="5">class="very-special"</f:case>
        <f:defaultCase>class="default"</f:defaultCase>
   </f:switch>
</f:section>
```

based on the version of your TYPO3 the template paths of FSC can be configured like:
(up to TYPO3 7):

```
lib.fluidContent {
   templateRootPaths {
       20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/
   }
   partialRootPaths {
       20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/
   }
   layoutRootPaths {
       20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/
   }
}
```

or (since TYPO3 8): [(Manual)](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/8.7/en-us/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/Index.html)

```
lib.contentElement {
   templateRootPaths {
       20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/
   }
   partialRootPaths {
       20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/
   }
   layoutRootPaths {
       20 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/
   }
```

}

Comment: how can I set a new path for the default.html?  can I add there some css as well?

Comment: its not for a plugin, its only for regular text-image content elements.

Comment: in modern configurations you use fluid for everything: whole page layout, layout of content elements, and of course plugins. they all have their own typoscript configuration and their own paths. my example is based on FSC (fluid styled content) where the rendering of the content elements (basic build ins and your own) is configured. I added the configuration of the FSC-paths

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me.

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject = CASE
    tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
        key.field = layout

        4 = TEXT        
        4.value = <div class="blue"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="design">|</div></div></div>

        5 = TEXT
        5.value = <div class="white"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="design">|</div></div></div>

        6 = TEXT
        6.value = <div class="grey"><div class="container-fluid"><div class="design">|</div></div></div>
    }
```

Comment: That is not he fluid way. That is like it's done with CSC. in FSC you would implement this switch/case in the Layout-template.

Comment: can you give me an example how I do it in FSC?

Comment: I enhanced my answer.